# Error loading shared libraries: libcairo.so.2

Tags: arch-linux, i3-window-manager

when I try to start i3 I get the error:

```
Error while loading shared libraries: libcairo.so.2:
```

(Then the rest of the the error is cut off)

How can I fix this? What does this mean? Note, I am an arch newbie and I was trying to get infinality working before i3 crashed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message means that the library with the name "libcairo.so.2" could not be loaded.

I guess you will have to install the library. Something like:

```
pacman -S libcairo
```

But usually if its a dependency it should have installed that library automatically. Best practice is to use the package manager of a distribution to install software. E.g.

```
pacman -S i3
```

P.S. more information about the system and the problem would make it easier to give you a specific answer.

Comment: I already tried the first command before asking this question, but much to my surprise, the second command actually worked. Thanks!